# Javascript get each value based on pray_name

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have data on table like this:

```
pray_name | time_before_iqamah
Subuh     | 1
Dhuhur    | 10
Ashar     | 10
Maghrib   | 10
Isya      | 10
```

And I generate it to PHP jSon

```
$qPray = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tb_prays WHERE active = 'Y'");
while($dPray = mysqli_fetch_array($qPray))
{
    $timeBeforeIqamah[] = $dPray['time_before_iqamah'];
}
```

jSon Result

```
{"timeBeforeIqamah":["1","10","10","10","10"]}
```

And now I want to get `timeBeforeIqamah` based on pray name on JS.

```
var list = ["Imsak", "Subuh", "Terbit", "Dhuhur", "Ashar", "Maghrib", "Isya"];
var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, geo, timezone);

for(var i in list)
{
    if(jsonStr.currentTime == times[list[i].toLowerCase()] + ":00")
    {
        if(list[i] == "Imsak" || list[i] == "Terbit")
        {}
        else
        {
            alert(jsonStr.timeBeforeIqamah[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Assume We are on `Subuh` time means what I'm trying to `alert(jsonStr.timeBeforeIqamah[i]);` should be get value: `1`, but What I got is: `10`

What I want is get `time_before_iqamah` base on pray name on JS.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the data in your table is not in the same order as the data in your `list`:

```
Index | pray_name | time_before_iqamah
0     | Subuh     | 1
1     | Dhuhur    | 10
2     | Ashar     | 10
3     | Maghrib   | 10
4     | Isya      | 10
```

Compare this to:

```
var list = ["Imsak", "Subuh", "Terbit", "Dhuhur", "Ashar", "Maghrib", "Isya"];

Index | Value
0     | "Imsak"
1     | "Subuh"
2     | "Terbit"
3     | "Dhuhur"
4     | "Ashar"
5     | "Maghrib"
6     | "Isya"
```

In the first case, `subuh` has index `0`, in the second case, it has index `1`, so it's impossible to match those.

To solve this, you could change your php, so you pass the names that match with the values:

```
$qPray = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tb_prays WHERE active = 'Y'");
while($dPray = mysqli_fetch_array($qPray))
{
    $timeBeforeIqamah[$dPray['pray_name']] = $dPray['time_before_iqamah'];
}
```

And then change your javascript to:

```
 if(list[i] == "Imsak" || list[i] == "Terbit")
 {}
 else
 {
      alert(jsonStr.timeBeforeIqamah[list[i]]);
 }
```

Comment: Worked perfect... (y)